# create grid from datatable

Tags: c#, forms, datatable, drawing

I have a datatable with this format

```
ID X-coordinate Y-coordinate
```

And I want to create a grid that has at the nodes the IDs and has lines connecting to adjacent IDs based off their X,Y location.  Any suggestions on doing this, I have never done any drawing before.  Thanks

Comment: give some sample coordinates and give some brief idea what do you expect from those coordinates.

Comment: lets say we do 
1 0 0, 
2 0 -1,
3 1 0
so we get an L shape

Comment: use Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, x1, y1, x2, y2) method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place a panel on a form:

```
private DataTable dt;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();

  dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
  dt.Columns.Add("XCord", typeof(int));
  dt.Columns.Add("YCord", typeof(int));

  DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
  dr1["ID"] = 1;
  dr1["XCord"] = 10;
  dr1["YCord"] = 10;
  dt.Rows.Add(dr1);

  DataRow dr2 = dt.NewRow();
  dr2["ID"] = 2;
  dr2["XCord"] = 10;
  dr2["YCord"] = 50;
  dt.Rows.Add(dr2);

  DataRow dr3 = dt.NewRow();
  dr3["ID"] = 3;
  dr3["XCord"] = 25;
  dr3["YCord"] = 50;
  dt.Rows.Add(dr3);

  panel1.Paint += panel1_Paint;
}
```

Here is the paint method:

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
  e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);

  for (int i = 1; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) {
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red,
                        new Point(Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i - 1]["XCord"]), Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i - 1]["YCord"])),
                        new Point(Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["XCord"]), Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["YCord"])));
  }
}
```

and the results:

[image]